# SwiftUI animation affecting other views

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

Here is my View:

```
struct HomeView: View {
    @ObservedObject var instance = Instance()
    @State var dotColor = Color.gray
    var repeatingAnimation: Animation {
            Animation
                .easeInOut(duration: 1.0)
                .repeatForever()
        }
    var body: some View {
        ZStack {
            TabView(selection: $selectedTab) {
                Settings(auth: auth)
                .tabItem {
                        Image(systemName: "gear")
                    Text("Settings")
    
                }.tag(0)
                ZStack {
                    MapView(locationManager: locationManager)
                    Color.black.opacity(self.instance.status.opacity)
                    VStack {
                        Spacer()
                        Button(action: {
                            print("clicked")
                            withAnimation(self.repeatingAnimation) {
                                                self.dotColor = Color.white
                                            }
                            self.instance.changeStatus()
                        }){
                            HStack {
                                Text(self.instance.status.text)
                                    .font(.system(size: 24))
                                    .fontWeight(.bold)
                                    .foregroundColor(Color.white)
                                Circle().frame(width: 12, height: 12)
                                    .foregroundColor(self.dotColor)
                                    .colorMultiply(self.dotColor)
                                    .overlay(
                                        Circle()
                                            .stroke(Color.black, lineWidth: 1)
                                    )
                                
                            }
                        }.padding()
```

My animation, changes the color of the `Circle()` from `gray` to `white` every second. However, it also changes my `ZStack` color opacity (`Color.black.opacity(self.instance.status.opacity)`) every second - even though it's not related to my animation.

If I remove the animation this weird behaviour does not occur to the ZStack opacity.

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can disable animation of some modifier explicitly, like

```
Color.black.opacity(self.instance.status.opacity)
  .animation(nil)
```